# Avanzar pasos en un formulario con fieldsets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tengo un `form` con múltiples pasos separados con un `fieldset`, y lo que deseo que haga es que el progressbar tenga `href` para que mande directamente al siguiente `fieldset`, sin modificar mucho lo que es el CSS. 
Cualquier respuesta se agradece.

Éste es mi código ([también disponible en codepen](http://codepen.io/guille1194/pen/NAaOqB)):

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
  if(animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show(); 
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = (now * 50)+"%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
      next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
  if(animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show(); 
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({'left': left});
      previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
  return false;
})
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/

  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;

  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Social Profiles</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Quiero hacer algo como lo que hace este código, pero aplicado al primer diseño  http://codepen.io/guille1194/pen/rLGqVb

Comment: Disculpen, no se si formule bien la pregunta, o si es algo difícil de hacer, cualquier respuesta se agradece :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo haría es crear una función para ir a un paso determinado y mantener el paso (step) actual en una variable.

De esta forma los botones "Next" llamarían a la función con el paso actual más uno, los botones "Previous" llamarían a la función con el paso actual menos uno, y los "li"s del progressbar llamarían a la función con el paso correspondiente.

Para añadir el efecto de link en los elementos del progressbar también le he añadido un estilo *cursor: pointer*:

```js
    var $form = $("#msform");
    var current_fs = 0;
    var animating = false;

    function gotoStep(step) {
        if (animating || step === current_fs) {
            return;
        }

        animating = true;

        var $step_fs = $("fieldset", $form).eq(step);
        var $current_fs = $("fieldset", $form).eq(current_fs);
        // deactivate next steps
        $("#progressbar li:gt(" + step + ")", $form).removeClass("active");
        // activate step and previous
        $("#progressbar li:lt(" + (step + 1) + ")", $form).addClass("active");

        //show the next fieldset
        $step_fs.show();
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        $current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
            step: function (now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                var scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                var left = (now * 50) + "%";
                //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                var opacity = 1 - now;
                $current_fs.css({
                    'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                    'position': 'absolute'
                });
                $step_fs.css({ 'left': left, 'opacity': opacity });
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function () {
                $current_fs.hide();
                current_fs = step;
                animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    }

    $(".next", $form).click(function() {
        gotoStep(current_fs + 1);
    });

    $(".previous", $form).click(function() {
        gotoStep(current_fs - 1);
    });

    $("#progressbar li", $form).click(function() {
        var step = $("#progressbar li", $form).index($(this));
        gotoStep(step);
    });

    $(".submit", $form).click(function() {
        return false;
    });
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/

  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;

  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>


    <!-- multistep form -->
    <form id="msform">
        <!-- progressbar -->
        <ul id="progressbar">
            <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
            <li>Social Profiles</li>
            <li>Personal Details</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
            <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
            <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
            <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
            <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: Bueno, gracias por la respuesta, pero en realidad, el problema que tengo es que quiero que el progressbar funcione como un href para los diferentes fieldset, sin modificar el diseño del mismo, de hecho, en codepen esta el plugin, para que realice la animación.

Comment: Vale, no te había entendido bien. He modificado la respuesta, creo que así te servirá.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me acabas de hacer el día :D, en realidad sabia hacer eso, pero solo con botones, pero eso haría que el diseño no fuera el mismo.